# Undefined variable, can't display data from a database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to display data from a database table
I am using codeigniter
elementary thing, but I do not understand what the problem is

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: record

Filename: views/main.php

Line Number: 55

controller Main.php

```
public function index()
{
    $data['records'] = $this->PhoneBook->get_records();
    $this->load->view('main',$data);
}
```

model PhoneBook.php

```
public function get_records($conditions = null, $limit = null, $offset = 0, $order = null)
{
    if ($conditions != null) {
        $this->db->where($conditions);
    }
    if ($order != null) {
        $this->db->order_by($order);
    }
    $query = $this->db->get('phonebook', $limit, $offset);
    return $query->result();
}
```

view  main.php

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td class="active">Name</td>
    <td class="active">Discription </td>
    <td class="active">Phone</td>
    <td class="active">Actions</td>
  </tr>

  <? foreach ($records as $record) {?>
  <tr>
    <td class="active"><?= $record->name ?></td>
    <td class="active"><?= $record->discription ?></td>
    <td class="active"><?= $record->phone ?></td>
    <td class="active">Actions</td>
  </tr>
  <? } ?>

</table>
```

Line Number: 55   is

```
 <td class="active"><?= $record->name ?></td>
```

array $data

```
Array
(
    [records] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => фффф
                    [discription] => ыыыы
                    [phone] => 8454
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => ппапрпр
                    [discription] => аааааааааааа
                    [phone] => 645645
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Are you sure that your query returns some records?

Comment: Yes, query returns:
Array
(
    [records] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => фффф
                    [discription] => ыыыы
                    [phone] => 8454
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => ппапрпр
                    [discription] => аааааааааааа
                    [phone] => 645645
                )

        )

)

Comment: Try to change $data['records] to $this->data['records]. Additionally you need to use <?php as opening tag and not just <?

Comment: And use <?php echo $record->name ; ?>  for your vars

Comment: If I using <?php foreach($records as $record){ ?> I have unexpected end of file, change $data['records] to $this->data['records]  not working,
<?php echo $record->name ; ?>  not change enything

Comment: You need to do that also here <?php  } ?>

Comment: Thank you, very match!  I do not understand why it is so but in other files, there was no need to use the full form...
it works now

Comment: Great :) Glad it helps. Anyway as additional note You should before you make the foreach() loop check if the $records is not empty otherwise you will get an error. It is a good practice to check for this and if thera are no records in the databse to show a message saying  i.e "There are no records yet"